# Do Facebook access tokens expire when a the admin user change his/her password?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

We all know that access tokens expires when their expire time is reached or when the user changes his/her password.

Let's say i have developed an Facebook App, obtained an page access token and use it for our purposes. I know that there is no expire time for page access tokens. Is the an "unless" situation for this?

I mean when do page access tokens expire? Do Facebook page access tokens expire when i change my password? I know that other tokes expire or they all deleted. Is is the same for the page access tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been 5 days and still no answer. So i have tried and check the situation.

And the result: Yeah they do. All access token expire after a user changes password.

I hope it helps.